# Найти сумму четных чисел в диапазоне от а до b

Tags: python

Пользователь вводит 2 числа a и b. Нужно найти сумму только четных чисел между ними (и включая их).
Не знаю как закончить код и правильный ли он вообще.

```
a=int(input("a = "))
b=int(input("b = "))
for i in range(a, b):
    if i%2==0:
        ??
print(sum)
```

Comment: А готовую формулу использовать? аль в школе не учили?

Comment: @Akina не учили, иначе зачем мне помощь?)

Comment: @Akina аль это что?

Answer (score 3):

> `for i in range(a, b):`

Во втором аргументе `range` нужно указать число на 1 больше, т.к. итоговый диапазон не включает последнее число, т.е. при `range(2,8)` мы получим набор чисел от 2 до 7.

> `??`

После того, как проверилось наше условие на четность, нужно сложить все подходящие числа. Для этого еще перед началом цикла нужно создать нулевую переменную (например, sum_numbers) и потом к ней каждый раз прибавлять каждое подходящее число. Это можно сделать через `sum_numbers = sum_numbers + i` или наиболее распространенный вариант `sum_numbers += i`.

Ниже представлен один из правильных вариантов:

```
a=int(input("a = "))
b=int(input("b = "))
sum_numbers = 0
for i in range(a, b + 1):
    if i % 2 == 0:
        sum_numbers += i
print(sum_numbers)
```

Comment: Осталось только не называть переменную sum, чтобы не перекрывать встроенную функцию питона

Answer (score 2):

```
a=int(input("a = "))
b=int(input("b = "))
ans = []
for i in range(a, b+1):
    if i%2==0:
        ans.append(i)
print(sum(ans))
```

проходим циклом по заданной последовательности, добавляем в итоговый массив данные соответствующие условию, потом используем встроенную функцию и получаем сумму.

Comment: спасибо! хотелось бы еще узнать, ans это что?

Comment: либо так: print(sum([i for i in range(a, b+1) if i%2==0])) в одну строчку

Comment: ans - answer - итоговый массив, куда мы будем командой append складывать данные, которые прошли условие. Название ему можно дать абсолютно любое, исходя из условий наименования переменных.

Comment: Зачем вводить лишнюю сущность - список ,если нужна только сумма?

Comment: @MBo Не, ну в каком-то смысле это шаг в правильном направлении, если потом переделать на списковое сокращение и sum от него, а потом и на генераторное

Answer (score 2):

**способ 1:**

```
res = sum(i for i in range(a, b + 1) if i % 2 == 0)
```

**способ 1.1:**

```
res = sum(i for i in range(2 * (a + 1) // 2, 2 * b // 2 + 1, 2))
```

**способ 2:**

```
res = ((a + 1) // 2 + b // 2) * (b // 2 - (a + 1) // 2 + 1)
```

тут просто решаем как сумму арифметической прогрессии

Answer (score 2):

Можно считать сумму только четных чисел с шагом 2:

```py
a=int(input("a = "))
b=int(input("b = "))
s = 0
for i in range(a + a % 2, b + 1, 2):
    s += i
print(s)
```

или однострочник:

```py
print(sum(i for i in range(a + a % 2, b + 1, 2)))
```